# Streaming from a WiFi webcam with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, real-time

I need to stream the video from my GoPro in real time using MATLAB, to do some image processing. I can see the video in VLC Player in:

http://10.5.5.9:8080/live/amba.m3u8

How can I read such URL in Matlab?

Thank you

Comment: m3u8 is a playlist, in a first step check what kind of stream is behind it. Open the file in a text editor.

Comment: This is what is shown when opening it, @Daniel:

#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:2
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:4807
#EXTINF:1.00000,
amba_hls-15.ts
#EXTINF:1.00000,
amba_hls-16.ts
#EXTINF:1.00000,
amba_hls-1.ts
#EXTINF:1.00000,
amba_hls-2.ts
#EXTINF:1.00000,
amba_hls-3.ts
#EXTINF:1.00000,
amba_hls-4.ts
#EXTINF:1.00000,
amba_hls-5.ts
#EXTINF:1.00000,
amba_hls-6.ts

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
I = imread('http://10.5.5.9:8080/live/amba.m3u8');
```

`imread` can read images from URLs.

Comment: That's actually the first thing I tried, but it gives the error 'Error using imread. Unable to determine the file format.'

Answer (score 1):

try to do:

```
cam = ipcam('http://10.5.5.9:8080/live/amba.m3u8', 'admin', 'myfoscam')
preview(cam) %dislay the images
```

this is from MathWorks:
[ipcam matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/ipcamera/ug/ipcam.html)

and here are more function to hendle wifi camera:
[IP Camera Image Acquisition](http://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/ipcamera/ip-camera-image-acquisition.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.